# WordPress get taxonomy terms by words

Tags: wordpress

I want to get existing terms by words.

For example: all terms on "products" containing the word "good" will be shown.

So we get: good books, good movies, good toys etc.

Look at this code:

```html
<?php 
$args = array( 'hide_empty=0' );

$terms = get_terms( 'products', $args );
if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
    $count = count( $terms );
    $i = 0;
    $term_list = '<p class="my_term-archive">';
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $i++;
     $term_list .= '<a href="' . get_term_link( $term ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( 'View all post filed under %s', 'my_localization_domain' ), $term->name ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
     if ( $count != $i ) {
            $term_list .= ' &middot; ';
        }
        else {
            $term_list .= '</p>';
        }
    }
    echo $term_list;
}
?>
```

I took it from https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms

This code show me ALL the terms from "products", but I want only the terms from "products" containing the word "good".

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your complete array of taxonomy terms, you can filter out terms containing the word "good" using PHP's preg_grep() function.

```
$terms = get_terms( 'products', $args );

// This will return all terms that contain "good" in some form, as in 'good books' or 'goodness'
$goodterms = preg_grep("/good/", $array);
```